# Oracle Q query escaping PHP

Tags: php, sql, oracle, escaping

I have the following PHP code:

```
function escape($field)  
{  
     return $this->db->query('select q\'{'.$field.'}\' e from dual')->row()->E;
}  


$name = 'L\'Enfant';
$sql = 'INSERT INTO FOO(NAME)  
        VALUES($this->escape($name)';
```

The string I get back will be:

```
L'Enfant
```

How can I ensure that my escaping is correct **WITHOUT** using a prepared statement.  This is **PURELY** an exercise in improving my understanding I am more than aware of prepared statements.

Comment: @ppeterka66 indeed if only oracle didnt use `'` instead of `\`

Comment: I was having doubts, so was trying to find the differences, and/or the source code for said function. But you were quicker...